# Recursion in Erlang functions

Tags: erlang

I'm having trouble understanding this piece of code:

```
{<<"block">>, Els} -> 
    JIDs = parse_blocklist_items(Els, []),
    process_blocklist_block(LUser, LServer, JIDs);

#1 parse_blocklist_items([], JIDs) -> JIDs;
#2 parse_blocklist_items([#xmlel{name = <<"item">>,
              attrs = Attrs}
           | Els],
          JIDs) ->
 case xml:get_attr(<<"jid">>, Attrs) of
   {value, JID1} ->
   JID = jlib:jid_tolower(jlib:binary_to_jid(JID1)),
   parse_blocklist_items(Els, [JID | JIDs]);
   false -> parse_blocklist_items(Els, JIDs)
 end;
#3 parse_blocklist_items([_ | Els], JIDs) ->
  parse_blocklist_items(Els, JIDs).
```

I'm not sure which function is getting called first.

> Els is empty, so that means that #3 gets called first, then #2, and then #3. Right? Why do we need function #3? What difference does #3 makes if #2 already returns JID? I'm lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, some terminology: `#1`, `#2` and `#3` are considered to be different *clauses* of the same function.

This is a common way to write a recursive function.  The function transforms some, but not all, of the elements of the input list into something else.

- `#1` is the base case: if there are no more input elements, we just return all the accumulated output elements (`JIDs`).
- In `#2`, the first element of the input list is an `xmlel` record whose `name` field is `<<"item">>`. We check for a `jid` attribute, and if it has one, we create a JID and add it to the list.  Note that we're doing so using a recursive call: we call the same function, with the first argument being the *remaining* elements of the input list, and the second argument being the existing output list *plus* the newly added element.
- If the first element of the input list doesn't match the pattern in `#2`, we end up in `#3`, where we just skip over it and keep processing the rest of the list.

If `Els` is empty, as you mention in the question, then we'll end up in clause `#1`, and won't actually hit the code in `#2` and `#3`.

Clauses `#2` and `#3` are similar in that both "consume" an element from the input list.  The difference is that clause `#2` *sometimes* produces a new element for the output list, while clause `#3` *never* does so.  They could have been written as a single clause; it's a question of style and preference.

Answer (score 2):

You have three clauses, each providing a possible match.

Your `#1` matches the empty list.
Your `#2` matches a list where the head is `#xmlel{}` with its `name` attribute being `<<"item">>`.
Your `#3` matches a non-empty list (i.e., any where the head is not an xml element with its name being *item*.

The match order is always from top to bottom. So a match will be tried on 1 then 2 then 3.

```
[] will match 1
[foo, bar] will match 3
[#xmlel { name = <<"item">>, attrs = something}, baz] will match 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The Erlang scheduler, when scheduling a function, looks at the argument and all available clauses for the function. It iterates over function clauses in the order in which they are defined until it finds the first one for which all arguments match their respective patterns.

So, if `Els` is an empty list, it will use clause #1.

If `Els` is a list whose first element is an `xmlel` record, it will use clause #2.

If `Els` is a list whose first element is anything else, it will use clause #3.

Clause #3 is a catch-all clause which is most likely being used to avoid errors when there are unexpected values in the list. This is a fairly common practice where it makes sense.

This is also a recursive function, so in clauses #2 and #3 it is calling `parse_blocklist_items` again, and will do so until it runs out of items in the list (and therefor executing clause #1).